# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the next query

```
SELECT *
FROM   Assoc AS cc 
       JOIN Orders AS o    ON cc.Referencecode = o.Orderid
```

I got this error:
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I solved by adding this clause…

```
WHERE  ISNUMERIC (cc.Referencecode) = 1
```

My question is… is it ok this solution? (I don’t havea access to change the datatypes…) or should I do a convert in the join itself?

ps: ReferenceCode is varchar(50) OrderId is decimal (18,0)

Comment: It depends on the business requirements

Comment: usually it's better (performance wise) to do this in the join itself.  Also it might be worth mentioning that this way you're excluding records that don't have a numeric reference code from your result set.  Not sure if this is your intent or not?

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Comment: @Chicago , did any answer worked for you or not

Answer (score 1):

`ISNUMERIC()` could give you false positives here. For example, run these queries...

```
SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE ISNUMERIC('$') = 1
SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE ISNUMERIC('1e4') = 1
```

Instead, it would be safer to use the following where clause, which removes columns that contain anything other than a digit.

```
WHERE cc.Referencecode not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

If you want to include decimals, you can use:

```
WHERE cc.Referencecode not like '%[^0-9.]%'
```

Or for SQL Server 2012 / 2016

```
JOIN Orders AS o ON TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC,cc.Referencecode) = o.Orderid
```

Lastly, you could convert them both to varchar, to not remove any rows.

```
JOIN Orders AS o ON cc.Referencecode = CAST(o.Orderid as VARCHAR(4000))
```

[TRY_CONVERT() Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: I was digging the "tri_convert()"  I think you stumbled upon a much needed feature... Phonetic SQL   +1 for the try_convert, however, you missed ISNUMERIC('1d4')

Comment: Java hasn't kicked in yet haha

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to do as below:-

```
SELECT *
FROM   Assoc AS cc 
       JOIN Orders AS o    ON cc.Referencecode = CAST(o.Orderid as Nvarchar(MAX))
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST(Varchar AS INT) You should convert it before comparing. If it is varchar.

Sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Assoc AS cc Nvarchar(MAX)
       JOIN Orders AS o    ON cc.Referencecode = CAST(o.Orderid AS Nvarchar(MAX))
```

CAST in this way which ever gives you error.

Comment: This is wrong. Orderid isn't causing the error according to OP

Comment: i think this soln will give an error on CAST(o.Orderid AS NUMERIC)

Comment: You can convert o.Orderid to Varchar, as according to output LHS and RHS have different data type. And I guess o.Orderid is numeric and cc.Referencecode is varchar. so you can convert numeric to Varchar so, that it will be easier to compare.

Or send me the Schema I will try to suggest you more better option.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little more work, but given the query you have will not scale very well once you have a large amount of data.

But if possible I would add a computed column such as

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Assoc
  ADD Referencecode_DEC AS ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,0), Referencecode, 0) PERSISTED
```

Add an index on your new column and when you run the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Assoc AS cc 
   JOIN Orders AS o    ON cc.Referencecode_DEC = o.Orderid
```

It will use the correct statistics and should produce a much better plan